# Pop up with message The app does not work without Google Play services while running calabash test

Tags: android, android-emulator, calabash, calabash-android, terminal-emulator

I am running calabash-android test by using an emulator. And it has been working fine so far on the mobile device and when it comes to the emulator I am frequently getting the popup message

```
The app won't run without Google Play services, which is missing from your phone.
```

My test is failing since this window is appearing frequently. Is there any solution to get rid of this issue. All kinda help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by creating an emulator that uses a system image which includes the Google APIs.

[image]

If you are using the command line, you would specify the system image you want to use with `-t <targetID>`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html

Comment: Thanks for the helping hand. But here the problem is that I am running this on Continuous integration. I can't see the window. And will have to manage it from terminal

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how to create the emulator through the command line.

Comment: That is correct, but I am running all things by using a circle.yml file and I am looking for some commands to avoid that message. And the following are the configuration for the avd. ** - emulator -avd circleci-android21 -no-audio -no-window:
        background: true
        parallel: true**

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another emulator try [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com). Just setup emulator with [google play services support](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support).